# -didDeselectRowAtIndexPath not called after setting cell to selected manually

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Inside of `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath`, I am calling `[cell setSelected:YES animated:NO]` for some of the cells.

For the cells that this is called, `-tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` is no longer called when pressed.

It is still possible to select a cell for which the call in `-willDisplay` was not made, and successfully deselect them after.

I'm not sure what is happening here.  I know of no reason why I shouldn't be using `-setSelected:animated`.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Please provide your `didSelect` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methods, so we can help you

Comment: You also need to call tableView's selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .Top) otherwise that cell would become unselectable (the delegate won't respond to tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath or tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath) . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you (also) need to call:

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition;
```

Comment: Wow.  Bit of an oversight on my part.  Thanks for the answer.